# Updating an item inside an array on Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've made a chat app and I want the user to be able to mark chatroom as favourite or mute the chatroom.

The structure of my database is like the image below

[image]

What I want is when user is trying to mute a chatroom or mark it as favourite,
 I only update the item that matches the chatroomId, But after a lot of searching, I found out Firebase won't allow you to update an element of an array and you can only add or remove from an array.

This is my function to mute or mark a chatroom as favourite:

```
static final Firestore dbReference = Firestore.instance;

static Future<void> currentUserChatroomChangeMuteOrFavouriteMethod({
    @required String chatroomId,
    @required bool muteValue,
    @required bool favouriteValue,
    @required ChatroomMuteFavouriteOption operationToBeDone,
  }) async {

 DocumentReference docRef = dbReference
        .collection("user_chatrooms")
        .document(CurrentUserDetails.id);

    DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
    Map<String, dynamic> docData = docSnapshot.data;

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userChatrooms =
        (docData["chatrooms"] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((chatroom) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(chatroom))
            .toList();

    for (int index = 0; index < userChatrooms.length; index++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatroom = userChatrooms[index];
      if (chatroom["chatroomId"] == chatroomId) {
        if (operationToBeDone == ChatroomMuteFavouriteOption.muteOperation) {
          chatroom["isMuted"] = !muteValue;
        } else {
          chatroom["isMarkedFavourite"] = !favouriteValue;
        }

        break;
      }
    }

    await docRef.updateData({"chatrooms": userChatrooms});
 }
```

So basically I get all the data, I update the field I want and I updateData again but this is not a good solution as I am also getting the chatrooms which I don't need.

How can I do this operation effeciently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a perfectly fine solution.  In order to update the contents of an array, you do have to read the document, modify the array in memory, then update the document with the new array.  There's really no way to make this more efficient, other than converting your array to documents in a subcollection.

Comment: The reason why I think it might be a bad solution is that if  the user has 100 chatrooms for example, Getting and Updating all of the array in order to change a field of an item is not looking  efficient  in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think you have an alternative, other than what I mentioned.

Comment: Great, Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Mine is a live video call app. I decided to put all active users in an array. To avoid high firebase charges(costs per doc read). So when a single user updates the array while another user pull the same array might lead to some users missing some details. Any person with a solution here.(a better way i could use)